# How to index a recursion loops in java

Tags: java, recursion, indexing

My code has a recursive method (`Generating_Circles`) that generates 3 circles randomly (`C1`, `C2`, `C3`), each circle represented by 3 parameters `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, then the circles are tested one by one according to a specific condition, let me say, if the circle `C1` didn't satisfy the condition test, then the method (`Generating_Circles`) will be called again to generate new 3 circles (`C4`, `C5`, `C5`) inside the circle `C1`, and the same procedure will be carried on for the new 3 circles and so on more circles will be generated recursively until the condition is satisfied, then moving to work with the second original circle `C2` and so on.

My problem is that I can't retrieve the proper indexes of the nested circles and for the parameters related to each circle.

So I will be so thankful if anyone gives me an idea of how to index the circles and their parameters for future work.

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: It sounds like you're building a data structure, a tree of circles.

Comment: Yes, that is right, my code is building a tree of circles

Comment: only work around i see is adding a static var or adding another param to a generating_circles to keep track

Comment: This really sounds like not the right approach at all.  Why generate 3 new circles if one is bad?  Why use recursion?  This problem sounds better suited to a while loop.

Comment: I have added a static counter to track the circles and that is ok, but the problem is indexing the parameters related to the circle, especially when returning back to the previous level of circles

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.